# Automatically merge Master to Develop on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Experiencing issues on Gitlab because the `develop` branch gradually deviates from `master`. For example, if somebody applies a hotfix on `master` it won't automatically appear in `develop` and that might create conflicts.

Is there a way for automatically syncing develop with master within the CI-CD process?

Related: [Automatically syncing develop with master on merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361787/automatically-syncing-develop-with-master-on-merge)

Comment: "if somebody applies a hotfix on master it won't automatically appear in develop and that might create conflicts" So why don't _you_ merge the hotfix branch to develop? That is correct Git flow. Why does a machine have to do it?

Comment: @matt we are already merging the hotfix branches on master, we want to merge master to develop or merge the hotfix to development after it. If we do this step automatically it will reduce the work. Isn't this what automation about? or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build off @matt's comment, there's no builtin way to do this in Gitlab or any other SCM/CI/CD system that I'm aware of, but there are a few options if you really need this:

1. You could register a webhook with Gitlab to send a hook when there's a push to main, then wherever you receive the hook can clone the repo, merge to develop, and push back to the remote.
2. Another option is to have a small pipeline job that is started by an API call to checkout develop, merge, and push to the remote. This would still require the webhook from the first option, but doesn't require cloning.

However, doing this at all can be troublesome if you have multiple people working on a project. Say you have someone doing work on Develop, whether that's dev work, testing, whatever, and there's a push to `main`, which is automatically merged into `develop`. This now messes up that first person's work. This can be fine if you're the only person on the project though.

As an alternative to auto-merging, one thing I do in my projects that multiple people touch is to add a simple Pipeline job that sends a slack notification when there's a push to `main`. It looks like this:

```yaml
Merge Notification:
  stage: "Send Notifications"
  image: centos:7
  only:
    - main
  needs: []
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - 'curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"There has been an update to the _*$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME*_ branch. Please be sure to rebase your non-merged code as soon as possible!\", \"icon_emoji\": \":gitlab:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/redacted'
```

I use the `centos:7` image here, but normally for these types of things I use the `alpine` image since it's <50mb in size. I made this job so long ago I don't remember why I used `centos`. Other images should work fine here too, so you'll just have to experiment.

- The `only: main` clause says that this job will only ever be added to the pipeline if the branch is `main`,
- The `needs: []` clause is relatively new to Gitlab. It lets you define a-cyclic pipelines, which just means that you can run jobs out of order. This example "needs" no other jobs from earlier in the pipeline, so it can safely run as soon as the pipeline starts, regardless of the stage. If you have enough runners available (or time, if using Gitlab.com), all eligible jobs can run at once, across all stages, depending on their `needs`.
- Next, we tell the job that we don't need to clone/fetch the project at all. the `GIT_STRATEGY: none` variable means don't clone the project from Gitlab.
- Lastly, the only `script` we're running is the standard `curl` command to send a message to a specific Slack Channel. This can be swapped for any other service if you don't use slack.

Comment: The integration with the Slack bot is an excellent solution, thank you.